# jenkins pipeline jobs are failing with [WARNING] 2023-06-16T19:30:31 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, pipeline

simple echo pipeline is also failing with below error all of a sudden .

```
[63.033s][info   ][class,load    ] hudson.plugins.clover.results.FileCoverage source: file:/home/was/.jenkins/plugins/clover/WEB-INF/lib/clover.jar
[63.034s][info   ][class,load    ] hudson.plugins.clover.results.ClassCoverage source: file:/home/was/.jenkins/plugins/clover/WEB-INF/lib/clover.jar
[63.036s][info   ][class,load    ] jenkins.metrics.impl.SubTaskTimeInQueueAction source: file:/home/was/.jenkins/plugins/metrics/WEB-INF/lib/metrics.jar
[WARNING] 2023-06-16T19:30:31 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:576)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:554)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:537)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$4.onSuccess(CpsFlowExecution.java:900)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$4.onSuccess(CpsFlowExecution.java:891)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$5$1.run(CpsFlowExecution.java:939)
```

tried removing plugins and added back